# How to accurately measure memory allocation in C# code?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm trying to test how much memory a part of my .Net Core code allocates, and I've came up with two alternatives, both give me answers which baffle me.

First attempt:

```
    var before = GC.GetTotalMemory(false);
    var temp = new char[1];
    var total = GC.GetTotalMemory(false) - before;
    Console.WriteLine($"Memory allocated in bytes: {total}");
```

For 1, 100, 500 and 1000 I get 0. For 10,000 I get 20048.

Second attempt:

```
    var before = GC.GetAllocatedBytesForCurrentThread();
    var temp = new char[1];
    var total = GC.GetAllocatedBytesForCurrentThread() - before;
    Console.WriteLine($"Memory allocated in bytes: {total}");
```

For 1, 100, 500, 1000 and 10,000 I get 32, 224, 1024, 2024, 20024 respectively.

What I expected:
2 * array length, since sizeof(char) is 2.

1. Which of the methods above is correct? If none, what is the correct method?
2. Maybe my expectations are incorrect?
3. If possible, I would like an explanation to the results and why they differ.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why wouldn't you expect all of the registers within the CPU to be considered *allocated*? I mean, you expect the *array pointer* to be allocated... so why not count the *other* registers you're making use of?

Comment: You're right. The pointer lives on the stack. So I shouldn't expect it to be tracked by the GC. I'll edit the question.

Comment: You're missing the point. Do you think the garbage collector doesn't count its own book-keeping storage as yours? That is *your* overhead, right?

Comment: Note that if you pass true to GetTotalMemory you get the same results as your second attempt. My guess is that false returns some cached value. I suppose it makes sense if internally the memory statistics are only updated on collection. With false you had to allocate a large enough amount (10000) to trigger collection and cause the stats to be updated.

Comment: @autistic since I'm measuring only the delta, I don't think book keeping of GC is relevant.

Comment: @mikez interesting. Still doesn't explain why the result for 10000 is different though.

Comment: It's obviously going to be more memory than just the data in the array. A bare object is 24 bytes by this measure. An array also has to store the length in an int. I also would not be surprised if there was some kind of memory alignment internally which might require some additional book keeping.

Comment: @mikez He doesn't think book keeping is relevant... ;)

Comment: @kDar The difference for the 10000 case could be counting allocation of an empty string[] args array as well, but that's just speculation.

Comment: @mikez Could be the 24 bytes is all the fields an array have, though it doesn;t compute for me: there are 3 bool fields, two ints, one long and one object reference. so it should be 3*1 + 2*4 + 1*8 + size of object reference, which I'm not what it is but I guess it's 32 / 64 bit. Maybe there is also some alignment going on and that's why we get 24 / 32.

Comment: @kDar I have no idea what you are attempting to count. From what I can tell, an object takes 24 bytes minimum (x64). My reading is that at least 16 of these bytes are pointers to internal data structures in the CLR (sync block and method table). The other 8 I'm not sure about, but it does seem like classes with only a couple of int fields can also fit in 24 bytes as well, so it makes sense that an array might be able to store it's length that way (a 0 length array is 24 bytes btw). There is definitely some alignment of the allocated data as well because lengths 1-4 chars all take 32 bytes.

Comment: @kDar A correct formula for the sizes you list (assuming x64) is `24 + 8 * (int)Math.Ceiling(2d * length / 8d)`. The 2 is for the size of char; the others are probably machine word size dependent.

Comment: @mikez I'm counting the fields of an array type. It has fields like IsFixedSize, Length, LongLength etc.

Comment: @kDar Those are properties not necessarily stored in fields. IsFixedSize just returns true. It's not stored anywhere.

Comment: @mikez nice calculation, though it is an extrapolation, so it might be proven incorrect on some other values. I've tried working around the instance overhead by creating a list with 10k elements, and measuring the addition of a single element. got 40000. frustrating

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176021/discussion-between-kdar-and-mike-z).

Comment: no results? if you found one, please write it as answer